# Quarkus hibernate and orm.xml null EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I have a very simple that I struggle to make it work the last couple of hours.
I have the following simple classes:

```
package com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Set;

@RegisterForReflection

public class Item  {
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  private long id;
  public String itemId;
  public String description;
 

  public Item(String itemId, String description) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.description = description;
  }

  // JPA default constructor
  protected Item() {
  }


  public String itemId() {
    return this.itemId;
  }

  public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
  }

  public String description() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

```
package com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.infrastructure.persistence;

import com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.Inject;
import com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model.Item;
import com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model.ItemRepository;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnit;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;


@ApplicationScoped
public class HibernateItemRepository implements ItemRepository {

  @Inject
  EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public void addItem(Item item) {
    em.persist(item);
  }
}
```

and last but not least a very simple controller to execute the whole thing:

```
package com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory;

import com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model.Item;
import com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model.ItemRepository;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/inventory")
public class InventoryResource {

    @Inject
    ItemRepository repository;

    @GET
    @Path("{itemId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(@PathParam("itemId") String itemId) {

        repository.addItem(new Item(itemId, itemId + " description"));

        return "success";
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm resources/orm_2_2.xsd"
                 version="2.2">

    <entity class="com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model.Item" name="Item">
        <table name="item"/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
            </id>
            <basic name="itemId">
                <column name="itemId"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="description">
                <column name="description"/>
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

So, as seen I want to use the orm.xml to map entities to hibernated. Then the only setting I have in  application.properties is:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
```

Now, when I execute the rest endpoint I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist(Object)" because "this.em" is null
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.infrastracture.persistence.HibernateItemRepository.addItem(HibernateItemRepository.java:20)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.infrastracture.persistence.HibernateItemRepository_Subclass.addItem$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.infrastracture.persistence.HibernateItemRepository_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:33)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.infrastracture.persistence.HibernateItemRepository_Subclass.addItem(Unknown Source)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.infrastracture.persistence.HibernateItemRepository_ClientProxy.addItem(Unknown Source)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.InventoryResource.hello(InventoryResource.java:26)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.InventoryResource_Subclass.hello$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.InventoryResource_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:33)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.InventoryResource_Subclass.hello(Unknown Source)
        at com.sgiaf.training.inventory.InventoryResource$quarkusrestinvoker$hello_02a67b16908f55e9aa20fb4489a502ac7da7e268.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:115)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:142)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

This error only happens if I use the orm xml to configure the entities. If I use the annotation based configuration everything is working fine.

Any idea of what I miss?

I have tried to also use the RedHat builds but the same error occurs. I have also tried to configure hibernate with a persistence xml and then the problem changes and becomes:

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManager and qualifiers [@PersistenceUnit("Inventory")]
        - java member: com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.infrastructure.persistence.HibernateItemRepository#em
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.infrastructure.persistence.HibernateItemRepository, java.lang.Object, com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.domain.model.ItemRepository], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.stgiaf.traininng.inventory.infrastructure.persistence.HibernateItemRepository]
        The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
                - Bean [class=org.hibernate.Session, qualifiers=[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default, @Any]]
```

Comment: why are you still using orm.xml ?

Comment: @Serkan: I really wanted my domain classes to be completely independent of any framework. Besides this , I really do not like the noise of annotations and whenever possible I try to avoid them and separate the concerns.

Answer (score 1):

> So, as seen I want to use the orm.xml to map entities to hibernated

Then you must either use the standard location for that file (`src/main/resources/META-INF/orm.xml`) or [configure Quarkus to use it](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#xml-mapping) (`quarkus.hibernate-orm.mapping-files = path/to/orm.xml`)

---

Also:

> I have also tried to configure hibernate with a persistence xml

You shouldn't need one.

> @RegisterForReflection

You don't need this on Hibernate ORM entities, Quarkus will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that is clear. It seems that for some reason the EntityManager injected by Quarkus is null. If I inject PersistenceContext it seems that it works. I do not know if this is a problem with Quarkus documentation or something else that I miss.

Comment: I can't tell without a full, runnable reproducer, unfortunately.